# Google oauth asks approval every time

Tags: google-oauth

I write Delphi/Lazarus app which reads and writes many Google Calendars for single user (me).

When I started I wrote ClientID and Client Secret in my code as constants and used then fine. I was prompted by Google for my app approval once, copy/pasted that key in my app and it worked fine. (60 days? ago).  I have not changed anyting in my code or Google account settings since then, but now Google ask for my app approval every, every time. I do save refresh token every time when I close my app. Currently I am the one and only user of my app, and I would it to quietly fetch me my calendars on startup.

Only thing I can think of is that I created Brand Account for my Youtube channel, but I did not notice if app approval question started right after this. Seems unrelated, or is it?

Comment: If you are using a server sided language you should try using a service account instead of Oauth2.    Refresh tokens shouldn't expire as long as you are not using that client id and secret for any other projects.   However they can expire its hard to know why.

Comment: I am not using server sided language. This is desktop application which connects to Google Calendars to read and write calendar events. 

I tried to remove my app permissions from Google account and register it again- does not help. 

My desktop app saves refresh token on every exit, and its different every time. You (and others) say it should not expire.

Comment: Why aren't you using a service account?   you didnt include approval_prompt=force did you?   can you post your auth code?